# changing admin site url

Tags: django-admin, django-urls

Is there a way to change the url to open the admin site in django? I don't want to use the default /admin url. I am new to django so please try giving a bit more detailed information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In urls.py, change the line that reads:

```
(r'^admin/(.*)',    admin.site.root),
```

to something like:

```
(r'^new_admin/(.*)',    admin.site.root),
```

so now instead of http://example.com/admin you'd use http://example.com/new_admin

Answer (score 6):

Sure, the file urls.py in the root of your project maps URLs to handlers. Just change the line

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

[more from Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls)