# How to rename "admin" static files in Django?

Tags: django, admin

When loading up the Django admin pages, you load in the default Django admin css / js files. For example, `example.com/staticfiles/admin/css/base.css`.

I've enabled a default Amazon WAF (firewall) rule that blocks all access to pages that have the word "admin" in their URL. This has been great so far -- as most bots love looking for `/admin` domains.

However, this ends up blocking the Django admin. I'm able to rename the Django admin url to `/manager` using one line of code in `urls.py`, however I can't figure out how to to change the admin static files' filepath. I'm currently getting raw, unstyled HTML in my admin as all the static files are blocked.

Ideally, in `settings.py` I could write:

`ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME = 'manager'`

and then

`example.com/staticfiles/admin/css/base.css` would get rewritten to `example.com/staticfiles/manager/css/base.css`.

How can I tell Django to look in a different folder for admin files?

**Note**

I am not asking how to rename the url for accessing the admin page. I am talking about the admin static files. The below code does change the admin page url, but does not change the url for the staticfiles.

`urlpatterns += [url(r'^newadminurl', admin.site.urls)]`

Comment: Why are you blocking access to `/admin`? Bots will still find your admin panel at `/manager`, it doesn't make it any more secure.

Comment: Your question about how to change the admin route has been answered many times. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968380/changing-admin-site-url

Comment: @robinsax `/manager` is an example name -- the new admin name I'm really using is a random string. I don't care about them finding it as much as I care about being able to block 1000s of random attempts to find my admin portal at a webserver level. My app has crashed from bots trying `/phpMyAdmin` rapid fire.

Comment: @robinsax That is a different -- I'm talking about the staticfiles which that answer does not change.  Edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @bones225, could you share your `settings.py`?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen what part? It is very long. I do not know which part would be relevant.

Comment: Add the whole thing if possible, and change any private data. Also, could you tell me what version of Django you are using?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen I don't see how that's relevant to being able to answer the question.

Comment: @Melvyn, there is something in Django <1.4 called `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`, it may solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed in `example.com/staticfiles/admin/css/base.css`, the url is based off of the folder structure.

Also, it should be noted that in django admin templates, static file paths are said to look into a folder named `admin` like so: `{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}` (admin static file paths are hard-coded).

```
# a line from admin/base.html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
```

This means that you cannot change the path after `example.com/staticfiles/` for admin static files.

But, can be done by copying the templates directory

- Copy templates directory from `venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/` to project base folder
- Find all the occurrences of `{% static "admin/` and replace `{% static "admin/` with `{% static "manager/` in the templates. Need to be careful not to change any other thing in the template files.
- Update `TEMPLATES` settings > `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

[Overriding Admin Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

---

Another possible way to achieve this could be rewriting the URL to remove or replace admin from the URL. Simply rewriting the URL would result in 404. Furthermore, server configuration for serving the admin static files has to be additionally added.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to edit the Django package directly. Anytime I update Django, I'd have to do it again. Re-writing the URLs seems possible, although I'm not convinced it'll work as my firewall is before NGINX

Comment: @bones225 true. You would be doing the same kind of thing if you were to customise the look of your admin panel. Core functions are not changed by just overriding the template files.  [Overriding Admin Site Templates Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You're solving the wrong problem. Firewalls have standard rules to get you started, but must be customized to match the environment they're protecting, not the other way around.

Renaming files and routes each time you install or upgrade something is time consuming and error prone. Make exceptions for routes that exist - they are valid routes, so teach the WAF about them.

Just think about it this way: you would never post a question like this:

"I've just bought a firewall. What application framework can I use that can be put behind it, without needing to change the framework?"

Comment: Hm - I disagree. AWS WAF has some default rulesets where it's all or none, and would be difficult for me to recreate. I get your point but I don't think it really applies, I think in many changes settings have to change to get different products integrated. Would it still the wrong question if the answer was as simple as "yes, just do ``ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME = 'manager'``"

Comment: It has nothing to do with simplicity. If your client's requirements dictate that /admin should be a valid route, then it's a valid route. All assets below /static, including the admin ones, are no harm to the application, so you should be able to exempt it. If the immutable WAF has rules that disallow SQL keywords in POST payloads, but your site is a blog about SQL, then what? If an application is designed securely, a WAF should only filter traffic that would be invalid for the application to begin with.